# Настроить кодировку UTF-8 для git на windows7

Tags: git

Всех приветствую.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с настройкой гит для windows7.

- Версия git version 2.28.0.windows.1
- Терминал mintty 3.2.0

Никак не могу решить проблему вывода текста на русском языке, когда выполняю git diff и git log, в консоли отображается нечитаемый текст.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

git log

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делал (НЕ ПОМОГЛО):

- устанавливал кодировку в терминале mintty ru_RU.UTF-8
- настройки гит

  core.quotepath=off

  i18n.filesencoding=utf-8

  gui.encoding=utf-8

  core.pager=iconv.exe -f cp1251 -t utf-8 | less
- в переменные среды добавлял LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8, LESSCHARSET=UTF-8

Команды ниже корректно отображают русские символы

```
less README.md

diff README.md 1.txt

gitk
```

Comment: А вот это зачем `core.pager` ?

Comment: не могу точно сказать :), брал от сюда https://habr.com/ru/post/74839/

Comment: Этой статье 10 лет и исходники там были в кодировке windows-1251. Выкиньте эту настройку

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо за помощь. Я удалил core.pager и теперь все корректно отображается. Сделайте ответ на вопрос, а я его отмечу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось решить вопрос (спасибо [@AlexeyTen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten) за помощь).
Чтобы корректно отображались русские символы в cmd, необходимо установить новую переменную в переменные среды через "Свойства системы"  (системные или пользователя)
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
после этого командная строка windows7, git diff и git log должны показывать русские символы корректно.
Только почему-то утилита git bash название файлов не корректно читает.
Для гит установил такие настройки:
gui.encoding=utf-8
это заставляет gitk отображать русские символы корректно